# Scala library dependencies in internal artifactory pointing outside

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, artifactory

We've got an internal artifactory server and one of my colleagues just put on there the get-coursier library I want to use.

But, when I try to install it through sbt in intellij, the dependencies it needs are trying to be pulled from an external repository, which I can't get to as I'm on an internal only network.

I'm pointing at our internal artifactory using a repositories file in my ~.sbt folder.

How would I define new paths for the dependencies so they would point at out internal artifactory server as well?

Any tips, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I add it to the `build.sbt`like

```
  val yourRepoRealm = "Artifactory Realm"
  val yourRepoUrl = "http://yourhost.com/artifactory/libs-release-local"
```

Important is that you add this to the settings of the module where you need it:

```
  lazy val sharedSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    ...
    , resolvers ++= Seq(
      yourRepoRealm at yourRepoUrl
     , "jitpack" at "https://jitpack.io" // add other repos
    ), credentials += Credentials(new java.io.File(".credentials"))
    , ...
  )
```

This expects that you have your credentials in the `project_root/.credentials`. like

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=yourHost.com
user=username
password=yourPwd
```

Comment: Thanks PME.  Will that solve the depencies as well though?  My current setup works for the initial library, as I've setup my .sbt/repositories file to point at our internal artifactory.  The issue isn't with downloading that library, but the dependent libraries of it.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I'm using .credentials as well, but globally not project specific

Comment: @user2160823 than you have to check in which repos you can find them and add these resolvers as well - I adjusted my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks PME.  I think I'm missing something basic here.  In order for your suggestion to work, I'd have to go and find all the dependencies, and the dependencies of the dependencies, and list them in that file.  That sounds way too onerous to me.  I suspect there's a way of defining what the dependencies of a library are, and then using that to inform the sbt to install them from the local artifactory server.  You may have guessed, I'm pretty new to this.  I'm starting to think that the ivy.xml file that comes with the library may hold the key here!  Thanks again for replying.

Comment: @user2160823 just try sbt compile - and it will show you which dependencies it cannot resolve. Than just google it - maybe this requires another resolver - at worst case you have to download it manually and add it to your Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks again pme.  Yeah, at worst case is my only option, as we have no other internet access.  I'd also have to raise a call to get someone else to add anything to our artifactory server, so it's a massive pain.  I need a process to accomplish defining my dependencies, and where I get them from, on the artifactory server itself.  That way I don't have to keep all the dependencies of all the scala apps libraries inside the apps themsleves. just let the artifactory server dish that information out.  I'm pretty sure this is what the ivy.xml file is for.

Comment: You should be able to set up the artifactory to mirror external repositories on demand, as long as the server has internet access.